# Instagram Access Token provided is invalid

Tags: python, instagram-api

----------EDITTED-----------------------

When i'm trying to send the next request to the API:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/nofilter/media/recent?access_token=MY_TOKEN
```

the following error apeear:

```
{"meta":{"error_type":"OAuthPermissionsException","code":400,"error_message":"This request requires scope=public_content, but this access token is not authorized with this scope. The user must re-authorize your application with scope=public_content to be granted this permissions."}}
```

When I'm trying to change the scope of the application via the security screen of Instagram (https://instagram.com/developer/clients/MY_CLIENT/edit/), this message appear:

```
We will start accepting Permissions Review submissions after Dec 3, 2016.
```

----------EDITTED-----------------------

I'm trying to retrieve data from Instagram API via my python application.
when i'm sending an HTTP request to the Instagram API, it's return me the next error:

```
{"meta":{"error_type":"OAuthAccessTokenException","code":400,"error_message":"The access_token provided is invalid."}}
```

My code is attached:

```
def parseData(self,hashtag):
        url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/" + hashtag + "/media/recent?client_id=" + self.CLIENT_ID
        content = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
        data = json.load(content)
```

I tried to get a new authentication key, but I have the same error

Comment: Shouldn't it be `"...recent?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN"`?

Comment: @JasonEstibeiro I tried the next request and the same error returns: https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/hashtag/media/recent?access_token=self.CLIENT_ID

Comment: Could you verify the access token again? The error states that your token is invalid.

Comment: I verify the access token again, and even delete the old one and request a new token.

Comment: Try printing the url before sending the request.

Comment: This is the url :https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/instavideo/media/recent?client_id=self.CLIENT_ID

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your app created after Nov 17 so need to be reviewed before go live.

> Apps created before Nov 17, 2015 will only be required to submit for
>   review by June 2016. We recommend that you update your product and
>   start the submission process sooner than later to avoid interuptions
>   of service.

For review submission

> How to Submit for Permissions Review
>
> ```
> Go to Manage Clients and select the app you'd like to submit for Permissions Review
> Click the Permissions tab
> Click the Start Submission button
> Describe the purpose of your application and how you intend to use each permission
> ```

Comment: In my case, my app is still in Sandbox. Shouldn't it work when in Sandbox?

Answer (score 0):

Is seems that Instagram change their API policy. in the 5 Dec 2015, new applications can be registered.